# Conditional wp_mail statement on post

Tags: notifications, wp-insert-post, wp-mail

I am currently posting from the front end using a similar model as http://voodoopress.com/2011/03/review-of-posting-from-front-end-form/.  I want to send an email to certain addresses based on the value of the "problem_type" field.  This is what I have so far.  This does not send anything at all, but I am at a dead end.  Ideas?  I only need 3 different emails.  1 if value is computers, 1 if value is phones, and every other value can be sent to a 3rd email address.

```
function new_post_creation_email($pid) {
    $problem_type = get_post_meta($pid, 'problem_type', true);
    $description = 'post_content';

    if ($problem_type == 'phones') {
        $to = '1st email here';
    } elseif ($problem_type == 'computers') {
        $to = '2nd email here';
    } else {
        $to = '3rd email here';
    }

    $subject = "New Ticket in ' . echo get_post_meta($pid, 'problem_type', true) . ";
    $message = "A user profile has been updated\n\n";
    $message .= print_r($description,true);
    @wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message);
}

add_action('wp_insert_post','new_post_creation_email');
```

Obviously the "1st email here" etc have been replaced with text email addresses in the real code.

Comment: can you use `print_r()` in assignment? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of things:

1. You're mixing ' and " in a very bad way!
2. You're `echo`ing inside a string.  Don't do that.
3. You're silencing any errors on the `wp_mail` function, so if WordPress is giving you an error you'll never see it!

First, fix your ' and " problem.  Your `$subject` definition should read like this:

```
$subject = "New Ticket in " . get_post_meta($pid, 'problem_type', true);
```

This fix also fixes the `echo` problem.

Next, remove the `@` from in front of `wp_mail` and turn on [WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) in your config files so you can see any errors that crop up.

Comment: Thanks EAMann!  This got it to work...I **sheepish grin** had it in the page template that was creating the post.  The final fix was to place this function in functions.php.  Beautiful!